# Writing data to Firebase results in different structure than expected

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to store the data in the following format,

[image: sample]

I have coded like ,

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Store_Images_Likes").child("12345678").child("abcdefg").setValue("Liked");
```

But,it returns output like,

[image: captured]

I don't know where I have done wrong.Tried many things but doesn't work. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code just seems to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Store_Images_Likes").child("12345678").child("abcdefg").setValue("image_liked");
```

I am sure you saved the data that way while you were testing, take a look that in your code it says "image_liked" and in the db "liked".

Try to wipe all the data from firebase and try again

Comment: I just needed a syntax. I made up that question for reference purpose

Comment: I dont understant you, could you explain a little bit?

Comment: I wanted to know the syntax  to store the data in the format as posted in the question